# Condicional para capturar informações de JSON via Pyhton

Tags: python, json, loop

Se alguém puder me ajudar.. Tenho um script Python que faz leitura de um arquivo .json que contem os serviços Web que preciso interagir.
Num primeiro momento, meu json só precisava conter um serviço e o script funciona sem problemas, porém agora preciso que esse json receba mais serviços.
Como poderia fazer para que o arquivo .py execute o primeiro serviço e depois o segundo, terceiro.... até finalizar a lista?

Código .json

```
{
    "service":[
       {
          "portalURL":"URL PORTAL WEB",
          "fsURL":"URL serviço WEB", 
          "fsLayerNum":0,
          "serviceuser":"Minha conta",
          "servicepw":"Minha senha",
          "fieldstoreport":["*"],
          "viewerMapLevel":19
       },
       {
        "portalURL":"URL PORTAL WEB",
        "fsURL":"URL serviço WEB", 
        "fsLayerNum":0,
        "serviceuser":"Minha conta",
        "servicepw":"Minha senha",
        "fieldstoreport":["*"],
        "viewerMapLevel":19
       }
    ],
       "filenames":{
       "lasteditfile":"lastedit.json"
    }
 }
```

Etapa do arquivo .py que no momento faz leitura do primeiro serviço contido no .json.

```
fsurl = cfg['service']['fsURL']
    if fsurl[-1] == '/':
        urlLyr = '{}{}'.format(fsurl, cfg['service']['fsLayerNum'])
    else:
        urlLyr = '{}/{}'.format(fsurl, cfg['service']['fsLayerNum'])

    portalURL = cfg['service']['portalURL']
    if portalURL[4] == ':':
        portalURL = portalURL.replace(':', 's:')

    viewerurl = '{}/home/webmap/viewer.html'.format(portalURL)
    sharingurl = '{}/sharing'.format(portalURL)
```

Answer (score -3):

Para executar o script Python para cada serviço contido na lista do arquivo .json, você pode usar um loop for para iterar, segue o codigo abaixo para você testar

```
import json
```

## Carregar o arquivo .json

```
with open('seu_arquivo.json') as f:
cfg = json.load(f)
```

## Acessar a lista de serviços

```
services = cfg['service']
```

## Iterar sobre cada serviço

```
for service in services:
fsurl = service['fsURL']
if fsurl[-1] == '/':
    urlLyr = '{}{}'.format(fsurl, service['fsLayerNum'])
else:
    urlLyr = '{}/{}'.format(fsurl, service['fsLayerNum'])

portalURL = service['portalURL']
if portalURL[4] == ':':
    portalURL = portalURL.replace(':', 's:')

viewerurl = '{}/home/webmap/viewer.html'.format(portalURL)
sharingurl = '{}/sharing'.format(portalURL)

# Coloque aqui o código para interagir com o serviço, utilizando as variáveis definidas acima.
# Por exemplo, faça uma requisição HTTP, extraia informações, execute operações, etc.
```

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).